# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcryptoki in java.library.path

Tags: java, hsm

I am working with HSM using java in Linux environment.  I am getting below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcryptoki in java.library.path'
>   
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
>   
>         at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
>   
>         at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
>   
>         at jprov.cryptoki.Cryptoki.(Cryptoki.java:73)
>    
>        at au.com.safenet.crypto.provider.SAFENETProvider.(SAFENETProvider.java:65)enter code here
>   
>         at com.cs.messenger.util.MACUtility.addProvider(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.cs.messenger.start.StartMessenger.main(Unknown Source)

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the lib jcryptoki is missing or your process doesn't have sufficient rights to access it.

Additionally you could have a 32 bit version of the lib and running 64 bit java.
(source) [Linux and Java are 64 bit. The native library is 32 bit. Any workaround?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1549239?start=0)